# Disk State is "failed" on RAID card

Tags: raid, hard-drive, failed

So I have a brand new SAS disk that I'm putting into a system with an unconfigured raid card. The disk is showing in a Failed state. The disk is brand new never been used before. I am pretty new to this stuff and I can't seem to find a reason besides DOA but anybody have any ideas?

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHJaH.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsCNv.png)

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHXa3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unplug SAS drive -> Set RAID Controller to Factory Defaults -> Plug SAS Drive back in (to ensure a good connection) -> Drive still failed? - NO? Proceed to config drive. YES? - Could be DOA, verify by testing in another machine.